# How to force Spring proxy generation for annotated @Transactional methods

Tags: java, spring

I use multiple `TransactionManagers` with `@Transactional("txXyz")` annotations. It works well in beans annotated with `@Component` and created during Spring startup. I have another type of beans that I create later in runtime via

```
applicationContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().createBean(beanClassName)
```

The latter approach successfully injects `@Autowired` resources and calls all interface hooks (e.g. `InitializingBean`). However it doesn't create transactional proxies for annotated methods. I have been looking around but haven't found an obvious way to force transactional proxi generation on `createBean`. My question is there a "legal" way to force transactional proxy processing for beans created when application is already running?

Comment: Remove the transaction logic out of the constructor of the bean and have it in a service or something. Transactions should appear in the service layer. And don't access the applicationContext. You don't need to.

Comment: Not sure why you think this logic resides in bean constructor. It is not. And transactional logic is indeed in the service layer. And your last advice seems ... incomplete :) I appreciate you trying to help.